# Why not "docker push" only publish the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

The image is built from Dockerfile. So instead of pushing a whole image (tens of MB at least), publishing a Dockerfile(only KBs usually) will save much space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Dockerfile can reference *local* resources (files present only on the machine where the image was originally built) which would not be on the target server, where you would attempt (and fail) to `docker build` the same image.

Those local files are included in the image through ADD or COPY directives, and the resulting image is pushed for clients to use.

Answer (score 0):

A Makefile is only a few KB, why does apt ship huge .deb files around ?

Most images (at least the "base images") contain lots of files (such as full Linux distributions) that have been `ADD`ed into them.

You cannot recreate such images from just the Dockerfile.

Even if you could, the build process (such as compiling applications) may take a lot of time, CPU, memory, even network access. You don't have to do that when all you want is just running a program.